# zend_pdf right to left languages problem

Tags: zend-pdf

i am using zend_pdf to create pdf files from persian language texts.

i have two problem:

1- i want to change document's direction to right to left as persian, arabic and some other languages are.

2- i use Zend_Pdf_Font::fontWithPath('myfont.ttf'); to set a persian font. but when i render the pdf document i see that characters are separated one by one. but in persian characters of a word are joint together.

thx in advance.

Comment: Did you end up using RTL with Zend PDF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i finally used [tcpdf class](http://www.tcpdf.org/) for generating pdf files using php. it has good support for RTL languages and UTF. it also has a good fiture for converting html to pdf.